# Icon button layout in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on Windows 8, VS 2012. 
I added a round icon to my button:

```
this.btn.Image = Properties.Resources.icon;
this.btn.Size = Properties.Resources.icon.Size;
```

Also my form has background image:

```
this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.sunset;
```

But I'm getting ugly form, where my icon button is square: the round image in the middle and gray color in the corners.

The question is how can I display form background instead of gray color?

[image]

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Transparency in winforms is a hack and doesn't really exist. The transparency colour is determined from the BackgroundColor of the element behind it I believe

Comment: Are you using Mono over Linux or are you working on Windows? On Linux, WinForms implementation is already ugly by itself...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round shaped buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708113/round-shaped-buttons)

Comment: Either make the the grey areas brown (if the Backcolor doesn't change) or use the 2nd answer from the [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708113/round-shaped-buttons)

Comment: @TaW Added the RoundButton code in form.cs and the follow text appears in form.cs[Design] "To add components to your class, drag them..." instead of existing form.

Comment: Use `PictureBox` instead of button and also use interlaced PNG Files to make your life easy.

Comment: um, what about the missing part of the error message ? You can drag a self-written control from the top of the toolbox, if it is error-free. Or go for reza's answer, working a little on the image..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set some property of your button to gain what you need:

- Change `FlatStyle` property of your button to `Flat`
- Set its `BackColor`  property to `Transparent`
- In `FlatAppearance` Set `BorderSize`  to 0.
- In `FlatAppearance` You can also set `MouseDownBackColor` and `MouseOverBackColor` to back color of form or the color you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very-very much! This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make you control have a transparent background and then use a transparent PNG as the icon and voila.

See this [Microsoft Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4(v=vs.85).aspx) with regards to creating transparent backgrounds on controls