How to create a windows xp style button on a winforms form1 on a Windows 10 on .NET 8.0
I would like to have the button style that was present in Windows XP in Windows 10.

While using the form designer in Visual Studio 2022,only available button style is flat and variations of flat in the properties window of the selected Window.
Is there a way to get a button that has rounded edge and popup appearance as shown in the above screenshot? (I am not looking for the exact style)
I am using Windows 10, .NET 8, working on Winforms in Visualbasic.net or C#, IDE is Visual Studio 2022 Community edition.

Just out of curiosity, why would you want to bring back this atrocity?

Not exactly a Win XP button, but this migth help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708113/round-shaped-buttons.

@KenWhite I love that button,i hate the flat style buttons

Just noting that by using the Standard or System FlatStyle (when visual styles are enabled) WinForms appearance is always adjusted to the currently executing Windows version. Forcing XP appearance on Windows 10 will make your application very unconventional. Though you can do everything by overriding OnPaint in a derived XPButton class, it's an insane amount of work to handle everything properly including different DPIs, high contrast modes, right-to-left regional settings, etc. And what about the other controls?
